# Isn’t it possible for anyone to manipulate my Firebase Database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Just wondering…
Since the initialization of Firebase is public in a script tag:

```
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "key",
    authDomain: "domain",
    databaseURL: "url",
    storageBucket: "bucket",
    messagingSenderId: "id"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>
```

isn’t it theoretically possible, with this information, anyone to manipulate the database?

Comment: No, as long as you use firebase security rules https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you set the permissions (realtime database rules language) of read and write data to a node in firebase database.

### Sample Application Scenario :

> Firebase Database Rules Design:

- Suppose a node (aka "parent") in which every user has the permission to create a child after auth.

  ```
  {
    "rules": {
      "parent":
          ".read": true,
          ".write": "auth != null"
    }
  }
  ```

> Firebase Database operations:

1. User 2 "push" data via "push()" and create a new child node (randomIdforchild2).

   ```
   parent
   |--randomIdforchild2
      |--resetparentData: false
      |--addData: true
   ```
2. User 3 "push" some data via "push(), resulting in a new child node (randomIdforchild3).

   ```
   parent
   |--randomIdforchild2
   |  |--resetparentData: false
   |  |--addData: true
   |--randomIdforchild3
      |--resetparentData: false
      |--addData: true
   ```
3. User 1 is adding data to parent node via "set()". This will reset parent node.

   ```
   parent
   |--childNodeNameByUser1
      |--resetparentData: true
      |--addData: true
   ```

For this particular scenario, you should rethink your data structure and node access permissions (firebase database security rules).

Due to the permission that every user have, an exploring developer "User 1" can actually issue "set()" request in place of "push()" which overwrites previous data.Here you need to restructure your data model.

It may vary in your case.

Hope this makes you clear.

Reference:  [Understand Firebase Realtime Database Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/)

Comment: Still, if someone just copy the Firebase initialization Script and use it. He could manually write into the database while it is ".write": "auth != null". I can imagine that he would create an app where he can log in and once logged in he could write anything to my database right?

Comment: @chitzui by structuring your data you can let user to add data to his node only and for analytics you can fetch data from user id node. It depends on permissions on paths that you set for user access. Paths that are not accessible to a set of user cannot be altered by user.

Answer (score 2):

Since Firebase is a cloud-hosted database, it needs to be accessible to your users. The information in that scripts allows everyone to find your database and thus access it.

But by implementing the security rules that @FowotadeBabajide linked to you can control who can access what data, and validate that the data is in the format your app expects.

The topic is incredibly broad, so I recommend starting with the [Firebase documentation on database security](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) and then reading some questions with the [firebase-security](/questions/tagged/firebase-security) tag.